# How to make Slick sync slider responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I have added two sliders using slick sync. I have no idea how to make them responsive. I have knowledge on how to make sliders responsive using responsive [], but I am not able to proceed with sync sliders.

```js
 $('.slider-for').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  fade: true,
  asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
});
$('.slider-nav').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.slider-for',
  dots: true,
  centerMode: true,
  focusOnSelect: true
});
```

Comment: Was this question answered? Since I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

As you kinda pointed to yourself, you will need to use the responsive[] section to make it work as intended. for example:

```
    $('.section').slick({
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '25px',
        infinite: false,
        arrows: true,
        initialSlide: 1,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 3000,
                setting: {
                    slidesToShow: 3
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 1400,
                setting: {
                    slidesToShow: 2
                }

            },
            {
                breakpoint: 800,
                setting: {
                    slidesToShow: 1
                }

            }
        ]
    });
```

The above example will show 3 slides between 3000px and 1400px, 2 slides between 1400px and 800px and 1 slide below 800px. As there is no break point above 3000px this will be the settings for any resolution widths above that as well.

I had lots of issues getting slick to work well, and sometimes the load order of the page has to be changed around to get it to work with other controls, but give that a go and see if it works for you.

Comment: The solution you have given is for a single slider. Not Sync slider. Sync slider has two sliders which are related to each other. If I click previous or next arrow, the content in both the sliders will change. I cannot use breakpoints for this slider.

Comment: What happens when you add the responsive option to both of your sliders? you should be able to control what each slider does at each breakpoint as if they were 2 separate sliders (because that is what they are effectively).

Comment: This will not work. Because responsive[] will be needed only when I have multiple slides to show within a slide, not when I have a single image/content within a slide.My "slides to show" and "slides to scroll" is 1- not 2 or 3 that I can break it while making responsive.

Comment: I should have started with this, what is it you are trying to achieve in terms of responsiveness? If you do not want to reduce/increase the number of slides shown, and just want it to scale correctly when the screen size is changed then you should just use media queries to control the size of the container.

You can also change more than just the number of slides using the responsive option.

Comment: I am using media queries to make it responsive(in terms of width, float, and size). The issue I am facing is the image on one slide and the text in other size is overflowing causing my page to scroll. in spite of using overflow: hidden I am not able to reduce the overall size of the slider and make it appear the same in all orientations.

Comment: Have you got a link to a test site available? Alot of the time (at least what I have experienced using JQuery) this behaviour is caused by controls that are wider than you expect but are floated so they don't affect the styling.

I had a similar problem that was solved by reducing the width of the inner controls, sometimes within the CSS files and sometimes via JS on the page (depending on what the issue was)

Comment: i don't have a test link.. i am working locally. I am attaching JSfiddle for my code